# How to run .exe files on Mac without virtual machine?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, software-recommendation, command-line

I do have one software(.exe) file which I need to run on my macbook pro. For that I need cross platform application just like wine in Ubuntu.

Can anyone suggest me the application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a wine port for OS X: http://wiki.winehq.org/MacOSX

From the project page:

> **Current Status (x86)**
>
> Wine works well on OSX for Intel based Macs minus a proper
> distribution package (Mac Application Bundle) to fully integrate with
> "drag and drop" and "open" or "open with" functionality. Wine also has
> shortcomings with desktop icon integration and execution of certain
> types of DOS or blended Windows/DOS programs.

(Notice that **Darwine**, the original effort to port Wine to OS X, was primarily written for PowerPC Macs. Some work was done to support Intel Macs, but it is [no longer actively developed](https://wiki.winehq.org/MacOSX#head-baccd4cb9b700559729316fad72aa2b49d7b11cd), so you are better off avoiding it.)

There are no official Wine packages available for Intel Macs as of this writing, so you'll have to use a third-party application like **WineBottler** (http://winebottler.kronenberg.org/), **PlayOnMac** (http://www.playonmac.com/en/download.html, for Snow Leopard and Lion). or **Wineskin** (http://wineskin.urgesoftware.com/tiki-index.php, for Lion and Mountain Lion).

*daviewales* has mentioned in a comment below a package manager I didn't know of called **Homebrew** (<[Link](https://brew.sh/)>). You may want to give it a try.

Otherwise you can try the commercial product **CrossOver**, which is basically Wine with, as Wikipedia puts it, various compatibility patches added, more user-friendly configuration tools, and commercial support.

You can download a free trial here: http://www.codeweavers.com/products/

Comment: See [wineskin](http://wineskin.urgesoftware.com/tiki-index.php) for a free wrapper to wine

Comment: Hi Jaume, thanks for your quick response. I've tried Darwine already in my macbook but as I'm using Lion OS 10.7.4 and it doesn't support PowerPC Mac apps so I think it won't work on my mac. Please tell me if there is any way to resolve the issue or any other third party app.

Comment: Wine will work on your Mac. The easiest way to install it is to first install homebrew (http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/) then open a terminal and type `brew install wine`, then `brew install winetricks`. Before you do that, however, you should search WineHQ (http://appdb.winehq.org/) to see whether your app works in Wine.

Comment: Note that to run an exe in Wine, you have to open a terminal, change directory to the one containing the exe file (e.g. `cd ~/Downloads`) then run the exe by typing `wine ./filename.exe`. You can't just double click the exe file.

Comment: @daviewa;es - it is even easier to use crossover or wineskin - the config is basically done for you

Comment: But Wine is more fun... =P

Comment: @Dhaval I don't understand why you mention PowerPC support and how it relates to your exe file. If you run Lion you have an Intel-based Mac, which is supported by Wine as stated in my answer. Furthermore, Apple dropped support for Rosetta in OS X 10.7 "Lion", which means that, as from this version, PowerPC applications won't run on an Intel-based Mac.

Comment: @Jaume The reason is that I've tried the way you suggested but when I run the setup for that an alert is coming with message that "PowerPC is not supported by this application",what does that mean ?

Comment: @Dhaval Now I understand. Darwine was primarily written for PowerPC Macs, and you have probably downloaded the PowerPC binary. Some work was done to support Intel-based Macs, but it seems that it is no longer actively developed, so I would avoid it. I think you're better off going for WineBottler (winebottler.kronenberg.org) or another third-party application mentioned in http://wiki.winehq.org/MacOSX#head-d4a2cb6359851f1e382111806a19df09899cec23. You can also give Homebrew (mxcl.github.com/homebrew) a try, as mentioned by daviewales above. I've expanded my answer to include this.

Comment: @jaume Yes..Thanks your replies were really helpful.

Comment: There is of course CrossOver which I personally think is heavily overpriced and WinOnX, which I think is available on Mac AppStore for a lovely price.

Comment: Also, it also depends on how the program (exe, executable) is written with, for example, programs that require .Net Framework or DirectX would require additional setup, like so in Linux.

Comment: `wine` can also be installed via `macports`, by [`sudo port install wine`](https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/x11/wine/Portfile).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answer, take a look at WineBottler: http://winebottler.kronenberg.org

This application deals with some of the technical side of using wine on OS X, like creating application profiles etc. It essentially allows you to encapsulate the .exe as a mac application, and run it natively in OS X without the need for running a virtual machine.

It is only in beta, but I have successfully used this to run various windows .exe applications under OS X 10.6.x (Snow Leopard). Be warned, not everything will work, but that is to be expected!

Haven't got round to testing it yet in Mountain Lion yet as I have only just migrated. Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for suggesting the winebottler but I'm already using this before your post :) though I'm respecting your help and giving up vote to your post..:)

Answer (score 0):

Virtual machine would be another best option for you. have a look here also -

http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/software/3376910/how-open-exe-files-on-mac-os-x/

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.